# Setting style in Chrome gives undefined is not a function, but fine in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have the following code:

```
    // Load the widgets onto the canvas
    function loadWidget(widgetNum) {
        var objWidget = document.createElement("object");
        objWidget.type = "text/html";
        objWidget.data = "widgets/" + widgets[widgetNum].type + "." + widgets[widgetNum].ext + parent.debugURL     // location of widget
        objWidget.className = "widget";
        var widgetName = "objWidget" + widgetNum;
        objWidget.id = widgetName;
        objWidget.addEventListener("load", widgetLoaded, false);
        document.getElementById("widgetContainer").appendChild(objWidget);          // Add object to dashboard canvas
        return widgetName;
    }

    // finish widget setup once the widget is loaded
    function widgetLoaded(e) {
        var loadObj = e.currentTarget;
        loadObj.style.setAttribute("display", "none");                    // wait until fully customized before displaying
   .....
```

at the last line I get an undefined is not a function error in Chrome (latest) but no errors in IE11. In Chrome if I put a breakpoint on the line I can inspect loadObj and its style, so it must exist, and the eventlistener wouldn't fire if the object is undefined. No jQuery.

So not sure what to do with this error in Chrome. Any tips?

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce in jsfiddle.net? Perhaps you can try `loadObj.style['display'] = 'none'`, but clearly it is the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately .style['display'] makes no difference. I'm having trouble simulating this on jsfiddle as the code loads up a HTML widget from a different directory.